# git/bitbucket error: Unable to make Pull requests. But can clone

Tags: git, bitbucket

Full error message

```
remote: Your credentials lack one or more required privilege scopes.
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/a/b.git': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I have write access on the repo, and the I've matched the ssh key in my .ssh folder with the one saved on bitbucket.

Comment: I don't think ssh keys have anything to do with https. Consider using `git@bitbucket.org` instead of `https://bitbucket.org`?

Comment: I used username@bitbucket.org to clone the repo initially, do you mean do git@bitbucket.org there and then try to make the PR? Right now I created a branch locally and am trying to push my changes to an intermediate branch by making a PR. I assumed it might have something to do with ssh because I was required to set it up initially to prevent an access denied error.

Comment: I’m saying that an ssh key doesn’t have anything to do with using https. — What does `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` output?

Comment: established a connection to bitbucket, authentication succeeded with public key and logged in as username. 
If this has nothing to do with ssh then what could the issue be?

Comment: Consider cloning the repo using the ssh url `git clone git@bitbucket.org:<username>/<repo-name>.git`?

Comment: The issue is likely that your credentials lack one or more required privilege scopes when using https.

Comment: That is the way I cloned actually.

Comment: That's cool. May you also share how you are creating pull requests? I had a thought that this may have nothing to do with git.

Comment: starting from target branch TB,
    ```git pull```
    ```git checkout -b new-branch```
    ```Adding changes```
    ```git add , git commit ```
    ```git push origin TB```

Comment: And it was the push that gave this error?

Comment: yeah, the push gives the error

Comment: What does `git remote -v` show? --- For future reference, pushing doesn't create a pull-request. Pulling is also not a pull-request. A pull-request is actually not a git feature, but instead a feature of git hosting websites/services.

Comment: git remote -v gives username@bitbucket.org/a/b.git (fetch) and  username@bitbucket.org/a/b.git (push)

Comment: Ok I think I got it, I'm supposed to push the changes to my branch first, then make the pull request to the target branch, right? So the error is that I'm using the target branch for the push command

Comment: Yes that's right. The source and destination must be different, either different branches or the same branch but different repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for future reference: Clone repo via ssh. (ssh:git@bitbucket.org/a/b.git)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [app-passwords](https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/) for a long time.
but it was not working for new repositories, it works when I created a new app-password